# Static type for ionic 2 Page

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to add a static type to my `.ts` file which is based off of a conditional in a click event, which equals an imported page.

```
  gotoNext(pageData) {
       this.conditionalPage = pageData.hasList ? ListPage : NoListPage;
       this.navCtrl.push(this.conditionalPage, pageData);
  }
```

At the top of the `.ts` file i have

```
import { ListPage, NoListPage } from '../../collections/app.pages';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-program',
   templateUrl: 'program.html'
})
export class ProgramPage {

   conditionalPage: any; // I would prefer this not to be any
   ...
```

I want to change the `any` to represent the ionic 2 Page, type just not too sure what type it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ionic2 pages are angular2 component so you can use:

```
conditionalPage: Component;
```

but the ionic2 tutorial use `any` as a type:

```
conditionalPage: any;
```

Comment: Has this changed? Because if I do `this.navCtrl.push(conditionalPage)` it tells me: `Argument of type 'Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Page'.  Type 'Component' is not assignable to type 'Page'.    Property 'apply' is missing in type 'Component'.`. I tried to import type Page from Ionic but it isn't exported. So, back to the `any` type seems to be the only way now.

Answer (score 1):

The type you are looking for is `Component`.

Try:

```
conditionalPage:Component;
```